# Laravel 5 ошибка 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

Сам laravel лежит в папке **site.ru/geo**, подскажите где я допустил ошибку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/geo', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

.htaccess который лежит в корне laravel

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess который лежит в папке public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

А вся проблема была в правах на папку **storage**

Comment: Вам прислать фотографию экрана, на котором маркером обведено место, где нужная строка в ваших скриншотах? :) Пожалуйста, вместо скриншотов выкладывайте код. Скрины смотреть неудобно, да и поисковик их не индексирует.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Выложил для тех кто может будет тоже спать как я)

Comment: да и собсна при 500 надо не скрины .htaccess выкладывать, а логи веб-сервера/пхп...)

Comment: Если решили вопрос, напишите ответ и отметьте его, как правильный. Остальное сделает автоматика. У нас не форум и пометки "[Решён]" абсолютно бесполезны :)

Comment: @D-side поправил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Папке **storage** нужно было дать права на запись.

Из документации:

> **Права доступа**
>
> Для Laravel может потребоваться, чтобы у веб-сервера были права на
>   запись в папки storage и vendor.